# Is taxiing a small aircraft on a residential street legal?

Tags: faa-regulations, taxiing

I live with the back of my house to a Runway that runs north to south almost perfectly.  I live on the west side of the runway, Across the street from me on the further west most side of the road lives my neighbor who owns runway rights,(his house is completely unconnected to the runway) which from my understanding grants him parking privileges at a designated area on the runway itself. does owning runway parking rights make it legal for him to taxi his plane all 200 yards down the residential road in between my house and his to park his plane in his yard?

Comment: at the end of the road there is a opening with access to the runway for people who mostly walk their pets and drive their vehicles to their planes, which is where he is taxing through

Comment: If his house is "across the street" then how is it "200 yards... between my house and his"?

Comment: What are the laws, rules, and covenants covering the street? Those things can be quite variable. The principal at the Silver Lake, Oregon school used to park his aircraft in the school parking lot, taxiing between there and the airstrip. And I used to taxi a 172 on residential streets there. That was all legal because, at the time, it was not expressly prohibited.

Comment: The road is 200 yards long. the road runs between my house and his. @MureyTasroc

Comment: thank you @Terry I will look further into my specific area then.

Comment: Maybe you could post a location on Google Maps so we can envision this more clearly?

Comment: This is a HOA or local traffic law question.  I'm voting to close.

Comment: @MichaelHall You want to close a three year old question with positive votes?

Comment: @Pilothead, yeah, silly me...  I didn't even notice the date!  It must have had recent activity because it popped up on the top of my list.  Still, I caused someone else to vote for closure as well, and I will stand by my comment that is less about aviation than many we close.

Comment: @Pilothead, you are welcome to your opinions, but this is a far cry from asking about making an emergency forced landing on a road.  This question reads exactly like a petty flying neighborhood squabble, with the complainant searching for ammo.

Comment: @Pilothead, which is precisely why i think it is a question for the local home owner's association, and not the internet at large.  We are debating opinion here, which never gets anywhere...

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't matter whether or not the road is residential, it depends more on public or private. If the road is a public road, taxiing an aircraft will usually not conform to state motor vehicle regulations without a pilot car and a permit. In rural areas where nobody cares, it doesn't matter. When there are enough people around somebody will object, and then it does matter.

An airpark preserves community access to a runway via residential roads by making them private, and not subject to state or local motor vehicle law. Rules are enforced by conditions on titles to property, or by reference on the title that the property is subject to rules made by an HOA or other organization of the sort. Look at your title.

I think it unlikely you bought into an airpark without knowing it, but if your street signs look like [this](http://www.nc-airparks.com/AA_Duchy_AP.htm), taxiing on the streets is probably legal.

[image]

Comment: It might help to consider what the prop might do if children were playing nearby.

Comment: @Robert DiGiovanni: Kids all too frequently get hit by cars, yet AFAIK no one has made driving on residential streets illegal.

Comment: It could be worked out locally.